# Where to find old portage snapshots for Gentoo upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, gentoo, portage

I would like to upgrade an old installation (2018) of Gentoo.
I tried installing the current portage snapshot but I got (way too) many package conflicts that I could not resolve.

So I thought that a solution could be to upgrade in smaller steps using old portage snapshots, e.g. in two-month intervals. In this way, possible conflicts should still be manageable.

I found some older portage snapshots [here](http://distfiles.gentoo.org/snapshots/) but the oldest one is only one month old. I have searched for portage snapshot archives on several search engines and forums, but I cannot find anything.

Does Gentoo maintain such an archive at all and, if so, where can I find it?
Also, as far as I know, portage does not include the package sources. So, are package sources archived as well?

Comment: Even [backtracking](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1062318-start-0.html) didn't help you?

Comment: @BlueManCZ: I have tried `--backtrack=30` but it did not solve the problem. In the page you linked, someone suggests to use `--backtrack=1000`, I will give it a try.

Comment: @Giorfio: Yes, the higher number you choose means the deeper it will go through the tree and it will take longer time to calculate dependencies.

Comment: You can also take a look on [this article](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Upgrading_Gentoo#Upgrading_from_older_systems).

Comment: @BlueManCZ: Thanks, very interesting articles. I might try https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Upgrading_Gentoo#Updating_old_systems. The first article says: "Older snapshots are often still available on some mirrors on the Internet or on specific locations dedicated for this purpose." But it does not say how to find such servers.

Comment: @Giorfio: You should ask on [official forum](https://forums.gentoo.org/). You will probably get more answers there. Also check [this thread](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1059876-start-0.html), but be careful. You can easily break your system. For that older snapshots I found only [this mirror](https://mirrors.sohu.com/gentoo/snapshots/) containing some portage archives from 2018 but only portage. I don't know how to use it or how it could help.

Answer (score 2):

Provided you were lucky enough to install `git` in your system before updates broken, you can:

```
cd /usr
mv portage portage-recent
git clone https://github.com/gentoo/gentoo portage
cd portage
```

And then find the alternative best suiting you to go back in time:

### Go back in history via `git-log`

```
git log
```

Then go paging down or do a search (if you use vim, regex might help) and find a commit close to when you last successfully updated. To me, it was around March/2021, so I did a search for `/Mar [0-9]+ [0-9:]+ 2021`  until its neighboring commits were also before or close to March 2021.

Once you find a commit you like, check it out with

```
git checkout <commit-hash>
```

In my case it was

```
git checkout 70b8ef2605acc363ea1a0347f9df23fa92590847
```

And then you can proceed to upgrading the packages. Then step a bit ahead of that commit and so on until you're up to date.

### Git-checkout data

Another approach was suggested in this forum thread: [2nd post in Portage Historical Snapshots Gone](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8419680.html?sid=fd674c9ccf8e7b7a2d45e1e0ac8a093d)

```
git checkout $(git rev-list -n 1 --first-parent --before="2021-03-31" master)
```

Then it should take you at that part in time.

### Go back in "chunks"

Say you found that going 200 commits back in the current position portage currently points was your sweetspot to get a reasonably working update stage (not too many, not too breaking, and perhaps before major profile upgrade). You can then start by coming back that amount of commits:

```
git checkout master~200
```

Once you are all upgraded (hoping you could find a mirror with those old packages!), then you can move a bit ahead with, say:

```
git checkout master~180
```

Check which packages are willing to upgrade, and go on.

### Don't sync!

Now you have your portage stuck with actual Gentoo repo, if you do an `emerge --sync` it will just replace all data with the current one. You can instead, assuming you want to go bleeding-edge,

```
cd /usr/portage
git fetch
git checkout master #ensure you're back to the branch
git merge --ff-only
```

If you never run --sync, you shouldn't have issues, or else you may need to reset the whole repo, usually `git checkout -- .` should do. Then the `merge` should work.

### Mirrors gone

Most mirrors don't store old packages/ebuilds for long, so you may need to cross your fingers. Besides, in your system, the list of mirrors should be outdated and some/many not work at all.

If you no longer have `mirrorselect` or some fancy tools to do the update for you, a good shot currently seems to use `http://distfiles.gentoo.org/`. You want to add it to the `GENTOO_MIRRORS=` line in `/etc/portage/make.conf`.

Comment: All portage versions are available to download from https://gitweb.gentoo.org/proj/portage.git/refs/tags. You should be able to run portage from the extracted archive contents.